# FileInputStream class method read(byte[ ] b) how that works?

Tags: java, fileinputstream

I don't understand how the read method works.why do i need the byte array as parameter to the method?

I am sorry if that is to obvious but i am n newbie to Java.

Comment: The byte[] b is where the bytes you read end up, the metod return how many bytes you have read.

Comment: It is good practice to always check on offical Java documentation, and only then ask questions [FileInputStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileInputStream.html)

Comment: This wraps a standard system call.  Most langauges have a method like this. Have you considered what the alternative would be and why you wouldn't do that?

Answer (score 0):

There are several overloaded `read` methods are there. If you just want to read input stream you can use `read()`. But if you want to store the data after reading the input stream you should use `read(byte[] b)`. Data will be stored in that array

Ref : http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileInputStream.html

Comment: So if i understand what you are saying the method read(byte[] b) reads the data from the input stream and then puts them to an array of bytes.But i dont undersand if this method puts the data into the array firstly and then reads them or it reads them firstly and then put them into the array.

Answer (score 0):

As per the [javadocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileInputStream.html#read%28byte[]%29), it reads `bytes` from input stream and puts it to `byte[]` upto the length of the `byte[]`. If the bytes left in input stream is less than than length of `byte[]`, only the bytes left will be added to `byte[]`. Rest of the values in `byte[]` will not be modified and remain as it was at time of initialization.